# Help me add volume to the mesh using geometry nodes (or modifiers)

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I created a electric arc (or lightning bolt) animation.

[image]
[image]

Please tell me how to add volume to the line so that it looks something like this:

[image]

That is, some volume in the middle and pointed at the ends. You can also use modifiers, but it would be great if they were geometry nodes.

[image] (Blender v 3.3.0)

Comment: You could use `Mesh to Curve` before and `Curve to Mesh` at the end.

Comment: @quellenform it wokks, but how can i taper the ends?

Comment: The node `Set Curve Radius` and `Float Curve` may help you to do this. To be able to set this radius individually, you feed it with the *Factor* that `Spline Parameter` gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate @quellenform's comment .. you could use a *Curve > Set Radius*, assuming the use of *Curve to Mesh*, somewhere down the line.

You could set the thickness with a bit of maths, but to keep the node-count down, maybe just use *Float Curve*:

[image]

.. and, of course, you could multiply the output of the *Float Curve* by a bit of noise, or whatever you need for the characteristics you're after:

[image]